# RedisError: Cannot perform full-text search operations like .match on field of type 'string'

Tags: database, redis, next.js

I'm new to Redis and can't find any good docs on querying database for specific value and then sort it.
I'm trying to get data from a database, I'm using NextJs & Redis-om

I tried doing this in my `/lib/redis.js`

```
import { Client, Entity, Repository, Schema } from "redis-om";

const client = new Client();

const connect = async () => {
  if (!client.isOpen()) {
    await client.open(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REDIS_URL);
  }
};

class Score extends Entity {}

const schema = new Schema(
  Score,
  {
    address: { type: "string" },
    score: { type: "string", textSearch: true },
  },
  { dataStructure: "JSON" }
);

export const createScore = async (data) => {
  await connect();

  const repository = client?.fetchRepository(schema, client);

  const score = repository.createEntity();
  score.score = data.score;
  score.address = data.address;

  const id = await repository.save(score);
  return id;
};

export const createIndex = async () => {
  await connect();

  const repository = client.fetchRepository(schema, client);

  await repository.createIndex();
};

export const searchScore = async (query) => {
  await connect();

  const repository = client.fetchRepository(schema, client);

  const scores = await repository.search().where("address").matches(query);

  return scores;
};
```

And fetching data as

```
  const router = useRouter();

  const data = router.query;
  const query = Object.keys(data)[0];

  const fetchScores = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("/api/search?" + query);
    const results = await res.json();
    // console.log(results);
    // setScore(results[])
  };
  fetchScores();
```

To simplify this, I'm passing an address that was meant to check database and if any address is found matching to that query address, return it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've modeled your address incorrectly.

When you set: `address: { type: "string" }` you set `address` up as a `TAG` field type in RediSearch, which does not allow full-text searches, instead you want to set address to a `text` type `address: { type: "text" }` which will support the full-text search capabilities of RediSearch.

Comment: I tried fixing it as 
`address: { type: "string" }, score: { type: "number", sortable: true, textSearch: true }`
Had to change from using address -> score